# Какие патчи на ядро Linux накладывают мейнтейнеры дистрибутивов?

Tags: linux, ядро, дистрибутив

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно почитать или, пожалуйста, объясните про патчи ядра Linux, которые накладывают производители дистрибутивов.
Могу ошибаться, но производители каждого дистрибутива (Ubuntu, Arch, Fedora и.т.д.) накладывают нужные им патчи на готовую Линусом Торвальдсом сборку ядра для их дистрибутива. Вот хотелось бы изучить какие это патчи и что они изменяют.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для debian и ubuntu в репозитории с исхожными кодами выложенны сами патчи как diff архив

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/linux-buildinfo-5.4.0-28-generic на панельке справа *.diff.gz

Они скачиваются командой `apt-get source linux`

Патчи для дебиан также доступны на отдельном портале https://sources.debian.org/patches/linux/4.19.132-1/

В арче патчи применены в git https://git.archlinux.org/linux.git

Comment: Какие патчи в Arch Linux? Вот я не нашёл ничего там по ссылке. Чистое дерево от Торвальдса.

Comment: @0andriy в PKGBUILD патчи никакие не применяются, а так тут в тагах есть всякая косметика https://git.archlinux.org/linux.git/commit/?h=v5.8.7-arch1&id=13c2d5cc731142ffd8f22aec0e644dcd99b78940

Answer (score 2):

Почти любой дистрибутив предоставляет возможность скачать сорцы ядра. Дальше можно скачать [ванильное ядро](https://www.kernel.org/) правильной версии и сравнить обычным diff/meld/любимой утилитой.

Самое простое, как мне кажется, это Gentoo - там все это видно открытым текстом - оно используется при сборке

Все патчи на данный момент доступны по ссылке [https://dev.gentoo.org/~mpagano/genpatches/trunk/](https://dev.gentoo.org/%7Empagano/genpatches/trunk/)

Fedora (думаю, тут и центось так само будет). Все подключаемые патчи лежат в [kernel.spec](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/kernel/blob/master/f/kernel.spec). А сами патчи здесь https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/kernel/tree/master

С Убунтой потчи все также. Можно просто посмотреть здесь [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.4/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.4/) (или выберите подходящую версию ядра)